# Forward specific localhost ports to same port at a remote IP with pfctl on macOS?

Tags: macos, firewall, port-forwarding

I'm trying to forward *all* traffic to a collection of ports on localhost to the same ports at a specific remote IP using pfctl. From what I understand, I can do this by routing the loopback connections to en0 and then using rdr to redirect to the appropriate IP address. I can't for the life of me seem to get it to work though.

I currently have something like this:

```
ports = "{ 1234 5678 }"

rdr pass on en0 proto tcp from any to any port $ports -> 123.456.789.123
pass out on lo0 route-to en0 proto tcp from any to any port $ports keep state
```

I tried refreshing pf by doing:

```
sudo pfctl -d && sudo pfctl -ef /etc/pf.conf
```

I'm not sure if it's not refreshing or if my rules just aren't working, but it seems to make no difference at all...